# Animate Action Bar Item Outside of onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-animation, android-menu

I followed this [tutorial](http://techiedreams.com/android-rss-reader-part-3-action-bar-with-animated-item/) on how to create an animated refresh button.

I would like to extend the functionality differently then they cover in the tutorial. I would like to call the animation **when the user clicks on the button, and also outside of the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method.**

I have a `TimerTask` that runs an `AsyncTask` every thirty seconds, and would like to start the animation on the `onPreExecute()` method and stop the animation on the `onPostExecute()` method.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    final MenuItem i = item;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh_option:
            new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
            refreshIcon(item);
            Handler h = new Handler();

            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stopRefresh(i);
                }
            }, 750);

            return (true);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



private void refreshIcon(MenuItem item){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplication()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_refresh,
            null);

    Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(),
            R.anim.refresh_rotate);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    iv.startAnimation(rotation);

    item.setActionView(iv);
}

private void stopRefresh(MenuItem item){
    item.getActionView().clearAnimation();
    item.setActionView(null);
}
```